# How to create an array of returned result set and count different type of values on each group from DB in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a dashboard where product details will show by company wise. I don't want to use group by in my query because it is using between and records (company) having status 'y' should count all approved value (NO) of status 'y'. it could be single, multiple record (products) for the company.

I tried to create an array but i failed because of one to many relation of company-status-approved. I want to loop the values for each company, so it should show all details of specific company during date period.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dashboard";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.company, p.status
FROM product p 
where p.startDate between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-08'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>company</th>
<th>total product count company wise</th>
<th>total count with y status</th>
<th>total count with approved status - NO</th>
</tr>";

$totalProductCountCompanyWise = array();
$countAllY = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$key = $row['company'];
if(!array_key_exists($key,$totalProductCountCompanyWise)){
$totalProductCountCompanyWise[$key] = 1;
} else{
$totalProductCountCompanyWise[$key] += 1;
}

if($row['status'] == "y"){
$countAllY++;
}

$sql2 = "SELECT p.id, p.company, p.status , ps.approved
FROM product p 
join productstatus ps on p.id = ps.id 
where p.company = '".$key."' and ps.id = '".$row['id']."' ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
$countNO = 0;
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
if($row2['approved'] == "no"){
$countNO++;
}
}

$companyData = array(
array("company" => $row['company'],
"totalProductCountCompanyWise" => $totalProductCountCompanyWise[$key],
"totalCountWithYStatus" => $row['company'],
"totalCountWithApprovedStatusNO" => $row['company']
)
);


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $totalProductCountCompanyWise[$key] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $countAllY . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $countNO . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
else {
echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Table Reference

```
/*
CREATE TABLE `product` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`company` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`productID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`startDate` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `company`, `productID`, `status`, `startDate`) 
VALUES
(1, 'ABC', 13245, 'y', '2019-02-01 00:00:00'),
(2, 'amazon', 13215, 'n', '2019-02-02 00:00:00'),
(3, 'google', 13345, 'y', '2019-02-03 00:00:00'),
(4, 'amazon', 13145, 'y', '2019-02-04 00:00:00'),
(5, 'amazon', 13145, 'y', '2019-02-04 00:00:00'),
(6, 'google', 13188, 'n', '2019-02-07 00:00:00'),
(7, 'IBM', 13177, 'n', '2019-02-08 00:00:00');

ALTER TABLE `product`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `product`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;

CREATE TABLE `productstatus` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`approved` varchar(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `productstatus` (`id`, `approved`) 

VALUES(1, 'yes'),(2, 'yes'),(3, 'no'),
(4, 'yes'),(5, 'no'),(6, 'yes'),(7, 'yes');

ALTER TABLE `productstatus`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `productstatus`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
*/
```

Desired Output

```html
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>company</th>
    <th>total product count company wise</th>
    <th>total count with y status</th>
    <th>total count with approved status - NO</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>ABC</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>0</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>amazon</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Google</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>IBM</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>0</th>
    <th>0</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use an aggregate query using `COUNT` with a `LEFT JOIN` for the productstatus table, grouping by the `product.company`.

### Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/778178/5

```
SELECT 
    p.company, 
    COUNT(p.id) AS totalProductCountCompanyWise,
    SUM(CASE p.status WHEN 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountWithYStatus,
    SUM(CASE ps.approved WHEN 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalCountWithApprovedStatusNO
FROM product AS p 
LEFT JOIN productstatus AS ps 
ON p.id = ps.id 
WHERE p.startDate BETWEEN '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-08'
GROUP BY p.company
```

Results:

```
| company | totalProductCountCompanyWise | totalCountWithYStatus | totalCountWithApprovedStatusNO |
|---------|------------------------------|-----------------------|--------------------------------|
|     ABC |                            1 |                     1 |                              0 |
|  amazon |                            3 |                     2 |                              1 |
|  google |                            2 |                     1 |                              1 |
|     IBM |                            1 |                     0 |                              0 |
```

Comment: Initially thought you were wanting only `productstatus.approved = yes/no` counts, realized that it was `product.status = y` after initial post.

Comment: yes now result set is correct. thanks for quick help.